# How can I create a plane using a point and normal vector?

Tags: regions, geometry

A plane can be defined by a point and the normal vector, but these have to be reworked before feeding to `InfinitePlane`

[image]

I could find two vectors perpendicular to the given normal, but they would be arbitrary and I think I should be able to just use the point and normal vector that I have.

Comment: You may want to use `Hyperplane` instead.

Comment: @user, `Hyperplane[]` is mentioned in the OP's own answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> A plane can be defined by a point and the normal vector

This is only true for 3-dimensional space. `InfinitePlane` is meant to give a 2-dimensional plane no matter the embedding dimension.  In higher dimensions, giving a point and normal is not sufficient to define a 2D plane.

Use [`Hyperplane`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hyperplane.html),

```
graphic = EntityValue[
    Entity["Chemical", "1,2Dichlorobenzene"], "StickMoleculePlot"]
plane = Hyperplane[{15.78`, 67.73`, -71.86`}, {-106.51`, -21.78`, -43.46`}]

Show[ graphic, Graphics3D @ plane]
```

[image]

Comment: Given any plane is there a way to extract its normal vector?

Comment: @user, that depends on how the plane is specified, but usually, yes.