# A better definition of InfinitePlane

Tags: geometry

Is there any reason why an `InfinitePlane` needs a point and **two** vectors? One would be sufficient. (The one perpendicular to the plane)

Comment: Because in **more than three dimensions**, a normal and a point do not uniquely determine a plane.

Comment: As noted in the answer below, you can use `Hyperplane` if you have a normal vector `n` and point `p`. An equivalent form would be `InfinitePlane[p, NullSpace[{n}]]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a plane using a point and normal vector?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/161205/how-can-i-create-a-plane-using-a-point-and-normal-vector)

Answer (score 1):

You can think about it like this: If you have only one vector, you can rotate the plane around this vector and it would still be valid. Your point would lie on the plane and the vector would point along the plane. You would get infinitely many planes that match this description.

Please see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(geometry)#Describing_a_plane_with_a_point_and_two_vectors_lying_on_it) for more details.

Comment: Since the plane is infinite, orientation doesn't matter, they will all be the same plane regardless of how you turn it about the axis, I think. Also, consider `Hyperplane` which works the way OP suggested. You could say the same about the hyperplane, so why does this work for `Hyperplane` and not for `InfinitePlane`?

Comment: In $n$ dimensions, `Hyperplane[]` is $n-1$ dimensional, but `InfinitePlane[]` is always two-dimensional. It is a fortuitous coincidence that these two concepts are equivalent when $n=3$.

Comment: @J.M. Exactly, they are equivalent for $n = 3$. That is what I was hoping to confirm. Consequently, WRI could have supported the point + normal syntax for `InfinitePlane`, as they did for `Hyperplane`, if they wanted to, they just chose not to.

Comment: Allright, I now take the cross product of my perpendicular vector with  {1,0,0} and {0,1,0} and my school geometry tells me that this should work.

Comment: @C. E., I agree that it was a deliberate choice to keep the concepts separate.